# Piping content with multiple spaces

Tags: osx, pipe

I was attempting to copy files listed in a text file into a directory such as:

```
cat files.txt | xargs  -I{} cp "{}" ~/Desktop/temp
```

However I noticed that some files would not copy over.  The files that wouldn't copy over had double spaces in the name such as "My   Document.pdf".

I did a little testing and simply piping an echo removes all the spaces except for one. For example:

```
echo "Hello         World" | xargs echo
```

simply returns

> Hello World

Is there a way when piping to tell it to preserve existing whitespaces in the content?

Comment: What is creating this 'files.txt'?  If it is coming from `find`, then you really should be using the -print0 combined with --null.

Comment: In any case take a long read of the docs related to the `-d`, and `--null` options.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs

Comment: No its not coming from find.  I was using cat as example.  I have a perl script that will show the paths of files coming from a OS X Smart Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` does an unfortunate amount of parsing on its input, and depending on what characters occur in filenames (spaces, quotes/apostrophes, backslashes, tabs, etc) it can mangle them in a number of ways. The best way to handle filenames is as a null-delimited list and using `xargs -0` (which turns off all of the parsing). If the file list were generated from `find`, this would easy (just use `-print0`). Since you're dealing with output from a perl script, I see two options: modify the perl script to output nulls instead of linefeeds, or if you can't do that convert them in the pipeline with `tr`:

```
cat files.txt | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 -I{} cp "{}" ~/Desktop/temp
```

Comment: Simplier than my sed approach.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in which I needed to replace a space with a backslash and a space on OS X.  Here is what I came up with:

```
echo "Hello        World" | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs echo
```

With this all the spaces are retained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r _file
do
    cp "$_file" ~/Desktop/temp
done < "files.txt"
```

`IFS` is set to null causes no splitting is performed, and `-r` tell bash escapes backslash character.